# Set environmental variable

Tags: python, path, environment-variables

I am currently installed two packages. One is called `pyqz` and the other one is called `pyMCZ`.

1) I installed `pyqz` by the command

```
pip install pyqz
```

2) For the second one, I download the package from github `https://github.com/nyusngroup/pyMCZ` and install it by the command

```
python setup.py install
```

I ran the second package, but it kept said the `pyqz` package is not correctly set environmental variable. Below is the warning:

```
  set path to pyqz as environmental variable :
  export PYQZ_DIR="your/path/where/pyqz/resides/ in bash, for example, if you want this scale.
```

The `pyqz` package is installed in the path `/Users/HuanianZhang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and I export this path in the `.bashrc file as below:

```
export PATH=/Users/HuanianZhang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PATH
```

But it does not help to solve the issue. How can I do to set the correct environmental variable, then the `pyMCZ` package can use the `pyqz` module?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two straight forward solutions:

1. Type source ~/.bashrc after you set the environment variable for the changes to be immediately visible in the current terminal.
2. Open a new terminal after saving .bashrc for the changes to get saved.